# How to propagate the value of a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable

What is the trick to propagate the value of a variable?

e.g. `Test="ABC"` and `ABC="xyz"`

I am expecting that `$Test` returns `xyz`. Any hack to to do this?

I tried `$($Test)` and `${$Test}` but am getting wrong output. Any similar approach I can try with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest:

```
Test="ABC"
ABC="xyz" 
echo "${!Test}"
```

Output:

```
xyz
```

This  is known as indirect expansion.

Comment: Thanks. Just to know is there anything like $($Test)? Since I have to use inside for loop

Comment: This is not known to me.

Comment: @Rock, that's starting to sound like you actually need something completely different (possibly arrays). You might want to ask another question about what you're actually trying to do in the end. (I would say to clarify this one, but I'm not sure if it's fair for Cyrus who already answered.)

Comment: @ilkkachu Cyrus answer is correct. But just for information I was expecting if we can have another alternative to achieve similar

Comment: @rock: If I think it exactly, then there is still a second solution. But unfortunately, a reflex-like downvote is performed by some users when a specific command is used.